# Markdown: creating nested lists with line breaks with specific indentation

Tags: markdown

I am trying to get the following output in markdown

```
 - item1
   - subitem1
   - subitem2
   some more info about item 1
 - item 2
```

When I add the two spaces at the end of subitem2 I can introduce a line break, but the next line starts with 2 levels of indentation, and I only need 1.
This is the code I have tried (asterisks are spaces):

```
 - item1
   - subitem1
   - subitem2**
   some more info about item 1
 - item 2
```

And this is the output I get:

```
 - item1
   - subitem1
   - subitem2**
     some more info about item 1
 - item 2
```

Look at the indentation of `some`

Comment: When I put one empty line above and below the info line, it sort of works. The line is indented correctly, but in some online editors the whole list breaks. Take a look at [this](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#paragraphs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding two line breaks after the last subitem?

- item1

  - subitem1
  - subitem2

  some more info about item 1
- item 2

Here's the code which gives above list:

```markdown
 - item1
   - subitem1
   - subitem2

   some more info about item 1
 - item 2
```